# Makefile errors for process management

Tags: linux

I am getting the following error when I compile the Makefile for process management. The `liblab1.a` file is also present in the directory.

```
Compiling server.c

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ./liblab1.a when searching for -llab1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llab1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsocket
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'server' failed
make: *** [server] Error 1
```

This is my Makefile. This seems to be a result of some missing library files although liblab1.a is already placed in the folder.

```
# Makefile for the lab assignment
# You are NOT supposed to modify this
# file.

all: server simplefork crack server1 server2
 // server.c compilation
server: server.c netstuff.h liblab1.a
    @echo "Compiling server.c"
    @gcc -Wall -Werror -o server server.c -L. -llab1 -lnsl -lsocket
```

Comment: I would suspect that the clue to the problem is the first line you list "skipping incompatible". This would seem to imply that whatever built liblab1.a is not compatible with what you are currently compiling. This could be due to a number of reasons such as built on a different architecture, or perhaps using incompatible compiler options. It's tough to know for certain. But that is where I would start looking.

Comment: My architecture is this. x86_64. How can I rectify it?

Comment: And what built lab1? ld is telling you that it cannot use the liblab1.a found in your directory. You have to find out why.

Comment: Along the lines of what others said but to be more specific: run `file liblab1.a` to check if it is actually an archive. If it is, run `ar xvf liblab1.a` to extract then `file *.o` to ensure each object file in there is x86_64 and not some other architecture/format.